# Why does "Bundle Install" give extra information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle-install

Whenever I run the `bundle install` command on my machine with Rails, I always get extra information that I know does not belong.  Why is this the case? Here is and example output from running `bundle install` on my machine:

```
Fetching from: https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
HTTP Redirection
Fetching from: https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
HTTP Success
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Query List: ["rake", "i18n", "multi_json", "activesupport", "builder", "activemodel", "erubis", "journey", "rack", "rack-cache", "rack-test", "hike", "tilt", "sprockets", "actionpack", "mime-types", "polyglot", "treetop", "mail", "actionmailer", "arel", "tzinfo", "activerecord", "activeresource", "addressable", "annotate", "atomic", "awesome_print", "bcrypt-ruby", "cancan", "mini_portile", "nokogiri", "ffi", "childprocess", "rubyzip", "websocket", "selenium-webdriver", "xpath", "capybara", "chunky_png", "coderay", "coffee-script-source", "execjs", "coffee-script", "rack-ssl", "json", "rdoc", "thor", "railties", "coffee-rails", "fssm", "sass", "compass", "compass-rails", "decent_exposure", "delayed_job", "delayed_job_active_record", "orm_adapter", "thread_safe", "warden", "devise", "diff-lcs", "ethon", "factory_girl", "factory_girl_rails", "faker", "fullcalendar-rails", "ice_cube", "jquery-rails", "launchy", "method_source", "rspec-core", "rspec-expectations", "rspec-mocks", "rspec", "nyan-cat-formatter", "polyamorous", "slop", "pry", "pry-rails", "psych", "rails", "rest-client", "rspec-rails", "sass-rails", "sqlite3", "squeel", "stripe", "typhoeus", "uglifier", "will_paginate"]
Query Gemcutter Dependency Endpoint API: rake,i18n,multi_json,activesupport,builder,activemodel,erubis,journey,rack,rack-cache,rack-test,hike,tilt,sprockets,actionpack,mime-types,polyglot,treetop,mail,actionmailer,arel,tzinfo,activerecord,activeresource,addressable,annotate,atomic,awesome_print,bcrypt-ruby,cancan,mini_portile,nokogiri,ffi,childprocess,rubyzip,websocket,selenium-webdriver,xpath,capybara,chunky_png,coderay,coffee-script-source,execjs,coffee-script,rack-ssl,json,rdoc,thor,railties,coffee-rails,fssm,sass,compass,compass-rails,decent_exposure,delayed_job,delayed_job_active_record,orm_adapter,thread_safe,warden,devise,diff-lcs,ethon,factory_girl,factory_girl_rails,faker,fullcalendar-rails,ice_cube,jquery-rails,launchy,method_source,rspec-core,rspec-expectations,rspec-mocks,rspec,nyan-cat-formatter,polyamorous,slop,pry,pry-rails,psych,rails,rest-client,rspec-rails,sass-rails,sqlite3,squeel,stripe,typhoeus,uglifier,will_paginate
Fetching from: https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rake,i18n,multi_json,activesupport,builder,activemodel,erubis,journey,rack,rack-cache,rack-test,hike,tilt,sprockets,actionpack,mime-types,polyglot,treetop,mail,actionmailer,arel,tzinfo,activerecord,activeresource,addressable,annotate,atomic,awesome_print,bcrypt-ruby,cancan,mini_portile,nokogiri,ffi,childprocess,rubyzip,websocket,selenium-webdriver,xpath,capybara,chunky_png,coderay,coffee-script-source,execjs,coffee-script,rack-ssl,json,rdoc,thor,railties,coffee-rails,fssm,sass,compass,compass-rails,decent_exposure,delayed_job,delayed_job_active_record,orm_adapter,thread_safe,warden,devise,diff-lcs,ethon,factory_girl,factory_girl_rails,faker,fullcalendar-rails,ice_cube,jquery-rails,launchy,method_source,rspec-core,rspec-expectations,rspec-mocks,rspec,nyan-cat-formatter,polyamorous,slop,pry,pry-rails,psych,rails,rest-client,rspec-rails,sass-rails,sqlite3,squeel,stripe,typhoeus,uglifier,will_paginate
HTTP Redirection
Fetching from: https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rake,i18n,multi_json,activesupport,builder,activemodel,erubis,journey,rack,rack-cache,rack-test,hike,tilt,sprockets,actionpack,mime-types,polyglot,treetop,mail,actionmailer,arel,tzinfo,activerecord,activeresource,addressable,annotate,atomic,awesome_print,bcrypt-ruby,cancan,mini_portile,nokogiri,ffi,childprocess,rubyzip,websocket,selenium-webdriver,xpath,capybara,chunky_png,coderay,coffee-script-source,execjs,coffee-script,rack-ssl,json,rdoc,thor,railties,coffee-rails,fssm,sass,compass,compass-rails,decent_exposure,delayed_job,delayed_job_active_record,orm_adapter,thread_safe,warden,devise,diff-lcs,ethon,factory_girl,factory_girl_rails,faker,fullcalendar-rails,ice_cube,jquery-rails,launchy,method_source,rspec-core,rspec-expectations,rspec-mocks,rspec,nyan-cat-formatter,polyamorous,slop,pry,pry-rails,psych,rails,rest-client,rspec-rails,sass-rails,sqlite3,squeel,stripe,typhoeus,uglifier,will_paginate
HTTP Success
Query List: ["listen", "compass-import-once", "compass-core", "haml", "archive-tar-minitar", "rcov", "hoe", "therubyracer", "win32console", "spoon", "ruby_parser", "yard", "sprockets-rails", "bundler", "actionview", "actionwebservice", "daemons", "tlsmail", "pry-doc", "configuration", "culerity", "celerity", "database_cleaner", "cucumber", "syntax", "spicycode-rcov", "test-spec", "camping", "fcgi", "memcache-client", "mongrel", "ruby-openid", "thin", "minitest", "rspec-collection_matchers", "webrat", "facets", "abstract", "racc", "tenderlove-frex", "rake-compiler", "rexical", "weakling", "bones", "rspec-support", "rails-observers", "text-format", "activerecord-deprecated_finders", "rack-mount", "json_pure", "libwebsocket"]
Query Gemcutter Dependency Endpoint API: listen,compass-import-once,compass-core,haml,archive-tar-minitar,rcov,hoe,therubyracer,win32console,spoon,ruby_parser,yard,sprockets-rails,bundler,actionview,actionwebservice,daemons,tlsmail,pry-doc,configuration,culerity,celerity,database_cleaner,cucumber,syntax,spicycode-rcov,test-spec,camping,fcgi,memcache-client,mongrel,ruby-openid,thin,minitest,rspec-collection_matchers,webrat,facets,abstract,racc,tenderlove-frex,rake-compiler,rexical,weakling,bones,rspec-support,rails-observers,text-format,activerecord-deprecated_finders,rack-mount,json_pure,libwebsocket
Fetching from: https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=listen,compass-import-once,compass-core,haml,archive-tar-minitar,rcov,hoe,therubyracer,win32console,spoon,ruby_parser,yard,sprockets-rails,bundler,actionview,actionwebservice,daemons,tlsmail,pry-doc,configuration,culerity,celerity,database_cleaner,cucumber,syntax,spicycode-rcov,test-spec,camping,fcgi,memcache-client,mongrel,ruby-openid,thin,minitest,rspec-collection_matchers,webrat,facets,abstract,racc,tenderlove-frex,rake-compiler,rexical,weakling,bones,rspec-support,rails-observers,text-format,activerecord-deprecated_finders,rack-mount,json_pure,libwebsocket
HTTP Redirection
```

and then later on stuff like:

```
remote: Reusing existing pack: 1306, done.
remote: Total 1306 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (1306/1306), 446.54 KiB | 94.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (567/567), done.
Installing rake (10.1.1)
0:  rake (10.1.1) from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/specifications/rake-10.1.1.gemspec
Installing i18n (0.6.1)
0:  i18n (0.6.1) from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/specifications/i18n-0.6.1.gemspec
Using multi_json (1.8.2)
0:  multi_json (1.8.2) from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/specifications/multi_json-1.8.2.gemspec
Installing activesupport (3.2.13)
0:  activesupport (3.2.13) from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/specifications/activesupport-3.2.13.gemspec
Installing builder (3.0.4)
0:  builder (3.0.4) from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/specifications/builder-3.0.4.gemspec
Installing activemodel (3.2.13)
0:  activemodel (3.2.13) from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/specifications/activemodel-3.2.13.gemspec
Using erubis (2.7.0)
0:  erubis (2.7.0) from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/specifications/erubis-2.7.0.gemspec
Installing journey (1.0.4)
0:  journey (1.0.4) from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/specifications/journey-1.0.4.gemspec
```

Comment: How do you know the information does not belong? :)

Comment: I've seen it run on other people's machines, and never have I seen `Query List` or `Query Gemcutter Dependency Endpoint API`.  But perhaps I'm wrong? Is this, in fact, correct?

Comment: Maybe something in `.bundle/config`?